# Error: Expected one matching request for criteria "Match URL: xyz", found none

Tags: jasmine, angular7

I'm at a loss at this point. I'm trying to test an interceptor:

TEST:

```
const testBedBase = {
  imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
  providers: [
    ApiService,
    CacheService,
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: CacheInterceptor, multi: true }
  ]
};

describe('CacheInterceptor with cached data', () => {
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;
  let apiService: ApiService;
  let cacheService: CacheService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule(testBedBase);
    httpMock = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
    apiService = TestBed.get(ApiService);
    cacheService = TestBed.get(CacheService);
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    httpMock.verify();
  });

  it('should respond with cached data if available', async( () => {
    const testUrl = `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/employee/123`;
    spyOn(cacheService, 'get').and.returnValue(mockResponse);
    apiService.getEmployee('123').subscribe(res => {

      // apiService calls http://localhost:3000/api/v1/employee/123 as tested in the interceptor

      expect(res).toBeTruthy();
      expect(res).toBe(mockResponse);
    });
    const req = httpMock.expectOne(testUrl);
    req.flush(mockResponse);
  }));
})
```

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    const cachedResponse = this.cache.get(req.url);
    console.log(cachedResponse, req.url); // this returns the http://localhost:3000/api/v1/employee/123 as seen in the getEmployee request
    return cachedResponse ? Observable.of(cachedResponse) : this.sendRequest(req, next);
  }
```

To my understanding the `spyOn(cacheService, 'get').and.returnValue(mockResponse);` should set the response of the `this.cache.get` request in the interceptor, but it doesn't. And I continually get:
`Failed: Expected one matching request for criteria "Match URL: http://localhost:3000/api/v1/employee/123", found none.`

If I remove the spy, the error goes away, but I'm not stubbing the response from the service in that case.

jasmine 3.1.0
angular 7

Comment: I don't see a call to your Interceptor code?  Perhaps HttpTestingController is preventing it from intercepting the apiService call ...

Comment: @dmcgrandle - the console log in the interceptor does run, and the req.url logged is the url in the `expectOne` call. I'm unsure if this is the correct way to test an interceptor, though most tutorials do it this way. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I had two things going on here. Since I was trying to return data and not send an actual HTTP Request, I should not be telling the httpMock to expect a request. I should be telling it `httpMock.expectNone(testUrl)`. Secondly, the mockResponse that I was sending with the spy, was not an actual HttpResponse that the subscription was expecting, I was just sending an object. So I needed to make a:

```
new HttpResponse({ body: employee.data.employee, status: 200 });
```

to send back with the spy.

Hope this saves someone else hours of work :)

Comment: This caught me out too, where I was calling `expectOne` in my own test.